# Importing product prices into VtigerCRM via web services

Tags: web-services, type-conversion, vtiger

I'm using `vtwsclib – vtiger CRM Web Services Client Library version 1.4`
and everything is working fine beside the import of prices.

The code:

```
        $module = 'Products';
        $record = $clientCrm->doCreate
        (
            $module,
            Array
            (
                'productname'       =>  $sItemName,
                'cf_753'            =>  $sSku,
                'discontinued'      =>  1,
                'description'       =>  $sDescription,
                'unit_price'        =>  $sPrice,
            )
        );
```

Now I tried to set $sPrice everything like:

```
    $sPrice = '5';
    $sPrice = "5";
    $sPrice = 5;
    $sPrice = 5.0;
    $sPrice = (float) '5';
    $sPrice = floatval ('5');
```

At every single import my price is 500 - not 5.
So my question: How do I need to format my price that it stays 5 after the import into Vtiger (6.4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
In the settings of the user by default it seems like the entry:
`Decimal Separator` and `Digit Grouping Separator` have both been set to `.`.
I changed the Digit Grouping one to `,` and now it's working.